# Linear transformations $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, but $A^2$ and $B^2$ are not

Tags: linear-transformations

> Does there exist a linear transformations $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, but $A^2$ and $B^2$ are not?

Definition of equality:

> Two linear transformations $A$ and $B$ are equivalent iff there exist invertible linear transformations $P$ and $Q$ such that $PA = BQ$

I decided to construct a counter example and find such equivalent $A$ and $B$ when $A^2$ is not equivalent to $B^2$.

I wonder how to show that there are no two invertible matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that $A^2 = X^{-1}B^2Y$. One case may by when $A^2 \neq 0$ and $B^2 = 0$.

1. $A = P^{-1}BQ$
2. $A^2 = (P^{-1}BQ)(P^{-1}BQ) = P^{-1}(BQP^{-1}B)Q\neq 0$
3. $BQP^{-1}B = B(QP^{-1}B) \neq 0$
4. $QP^{-1}B \neq B$, because $B^2 = BB=0$
5. $QP^{-1} \neq 1$ - necessary but not sufficient condition

Then I just found two invertible 2*2 matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $QP^{-1} \neq 1$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, to construct a counter example.

I would appreciate it someone shows better solution.

Comment: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, $P=I_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that over any field, two matrices are equivalent if and only if they have the same rank, just consider:
$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $B= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ both having rank $1$.

You get $A^2=0$ which has rank $0$ and $B^2=B $ having rank $1$.

Comment: $A$ is the counterexample to pretty much everything!